# Session scoped bean serialization Autowire issue

Tags: java, spring, redis, jackson, spring-session

I have a simple set of two beans.

```
@Service
@Scope(scopeName = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class CartServiceImpl implements Serializable {

      private ProductService productService;

      @Autowired
      public CartService(ProductService productService) {
            this.productService = productService;
      }

}

public interface ProductService {
    // some methods
}

@Service
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {
    // some logic
}
```

I use Spring session with Redis to store the Session data. All works fine if I use standard Java serialization but if I try to add `GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer` I got Jackson serialization exception like below in this post. Why I got that? How I understand Jackson should support proxied beans serialization. What Is wrong.

P.S. I know about `transient` and `@JsonIgnore`. Here is not a case for them.

> No serializer found for class org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: ru.geekbrains.service.CartServiceImpl["productService"]->ru.geekbrains.service.ProductServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b87663be["targetSource"]->org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource["beanFactory"]->org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory["beanExpressionResolver"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: ru.geekbrains.service.CartServiceImpl["productService"]->ru.geekbrains.service.ProductServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b87663be["targetSource"]->org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource["beanFactory"]->org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory["beanExpressionResolver"])

Comment: `*Service` classes are not regular `POJO` classes. `Jackson` tries to find `getters`/`fields` for given class and if there is no fields it throws by default exception. You can disable `SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS` feature and allow to write empty `{}` objects. But why do you want to store these instances? Do they store state?

Comment: Yes. I want to have kind of stateful spring bean. Looks like such kind of beans in Spring have to be like pure DAO classes. Nice if I'm wrong))

Comment: That's a bad idea generally, if you don't have a good reason don't do this. Much better is to have a method which returns this `state` and serialise it directly. In other case you need to implement custom serialiser/deserialiser for service class.

Comment: Very likely that you are right. Looks like session-scoped spring beans should be as simple as possible. Without any injections etc.